# ClientScript registerClientScriptblock() not inserting script

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I've been trying to get a simple alert to show up once an onClick event calls a clicked funtion. I've used this to try and make it happen but nothing gets updated in the DOM and no alert shows up :(

This is the call I'm making to achieve what i described above, I've tried different varients too such as RegisterOnSubmin and RegisterStartUp. Would appreciate any help.

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = this.Response;
httpResponse.Clear();
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "loginClicked", "alert('ehllo')", true);
sendJNLPResponse(httpResponse);
httpResponse.End();
```

Comment: Have you verified your method is even reached?

Comment: @mason yes I can confirm, I have been stepping through with a debugger and it has been hitting that line

Comment: Do you perform a `Response.Redirect` after registering the script? Or do you create any other keys with the same type and key?

Comment: @mason updated question with the other things I do in that scope. I dont think I performed a redirect, but I did create another with the same type but different key

Comment: What is `sendJNLPResponse`?

Comment: httpresponse with contentType set to application/x-java-jnlp-file

Comment: Try removing that line. It's probably interfering with the full post back.

Comment: @mason don't think it changed anything.

Comment: Try removing every line except the script block registration.

Comment: @mason that did it, looks like something there is breaking it. Those are the only lines I have there btw

Comment: You don't need any of that except the script block registration. If you need to load another file, do it in a separate HTTP request.

Comment: @mason I would love to make changes but I can't :P I don't have authority but this will be an interesting fix